# How to get values from form and print it using (only) php

Tags: php, html, forms

Its a simple thing, I want to enter a name and after clicking the submit button I want to print the name just bellow the form ---simple!

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['one'];
?>

<!DocType HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            <u> <h3>
                Please enter your name:  
                </h3>   
            </u>
        </p>

        <form method = "post">
            <input type = "text" name = "one">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
        </form>

            <p>
            <u> <h3>
                You just entered:  
                </h3>   
            </u>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But its not working. The rule is it must be done using only php. I'm guessing something is wrong in the input tag for submit but not sure what it is.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I don't know, but have you tried it without these unnecessary spaces in `name="one"`?

Comment: @AndyLester, I got no result. after clicking the submit button nothing shows.

Comment: You're echoing something outside of the HTML document, so if you viewed the source you might see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this:**

```
<h3>
You just entered:  <?php echo isset($_POST['one'])?$_POST['one']:""?>
</h3>
```

*even better*

```
You just entered:  <?php echo isset($_POST['one'])&&!empty($_POST['one'])?$_POST['one']:""?>
```

also optional(in HTML 5) but is good practice to add action in the form field

example

```
<form method = "post"  action="self.php">
```

Comment: The action property is optional in HTML5, not that it was required in HTML4, but it wouldn't validate back then.

Comment: actully in 4 it is required, not that browsers cared

Comment: @Dagon true, I should have been clearer. It was technically (and after specs) required, but no-one seemed to care :P

Comment: browsers-smart enough to work it out, or dumb enough to allow people to write crap html.

Comment: well, it worked! and it worked without writing the action="self.php" , and now I understand that  "isset" was the solution. thanks :) @subhanker

Comment: @Giliweed using action is optional but a good practice ,anyways glad it helped .

Answer (score 0):

Include error checking, place the variable where you want it to appear and make sure the form action is set to itself (not required in HTML5):

```
<?php
// display errors
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            <u> <h3>
                Please enter your name:  
                </h3>   
            </u>
        </p>

        <form method = "post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <input type = "text" name = "one">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
        </form>

            <p>
            <u> <h3>
                You just entered:  
                <?php
                if(!empty($_POST['one']) && isset($_POST['one'])) {
                    echo $_POST['one'];
                }
                ?>
                </h3>   
            </u>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only one (so far)  that answers the question using the proper method `isset()`

Comment: Yet, doing `if(isset($_POST['one']) && !empty($_POST['one'])){...}` would be slightly better, while checking if it is not left empty ;-)

Comment: I'll edit with your update @Fred-ii- because that is *much* better ;-)

Comment: Maybe even adding an `else{ echo "Enter something"; }` - wink. *Just another 2 cents* - We'll have almost a whole nickel if we keep this up ;-)

Comment: If we were to apply all of the belts and all of the suspenders to this example it would start to look pretty gnarly @Fred-ii- ;-)

Comment: Are those still in style?

Comment: Yes, but not at the same time.

Comment: Thankfully. Otherwise, Herb Tarlek would come back with a vengeance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <!DocType HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <p>
        <u> <h3>
            Please enter your name:  
            </h3>   
        </u>
    </p>

    <form method = "post" method=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>>
        <input type = "text" name = "one">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>

        <p>
        <u> <h3>
            You just entered: 
                <?php 
                if(!empty($_POST['one']) && isset($_POST['one'])) {
                    echo $_POST['one'];
                 }
                ?> 
            </h3>   
        </u>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: I just tried your solution and got this error: E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: one -- at line 20

Comment: why is the error  saying "one" is an undefined index? @Ashish

Comment: @Giliweed its because when you load a page its an get request and `$_POST` variable is empty.

Comment: Please use  isset . if (isset($_POST['one']){  //echo here }  as the variable is not set on page load.